# Echoing only once inside a loop

Tags: php

i have bit of a puzzle Im unable to crack. I have dynamic table looping:

```
echo "<table border='1' padding='2' cellspacing='0' ";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Producto</th> <th>Ud/Caja</th> <th>Formato</th>  <th>Cajas</th> <th>Sueltas</th> <th>Total</th> </tr>";
// 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // trying to a title line 
    if ($row['proveedor']=="Campocerrado" ) 
    { 

    echo "<tr> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th>  <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> </tr>";


     ;
    ;}

    //

    echo "<tr>";
    echo  "<td>" . $row['idItem'] . "</td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenidItem[]" id="hiddenField" value="'. $row['idItem'] .'">'; 

    echo "<td>" .  $row['producto'] . "</td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenProducto[]" id="hiddenField" value="'. $row['producto'] .'">';

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="proveedor[]" id="lastValue" value="'. $row['proveedor'] .'">'; 

    echo "<td>" .  $row['ud/caja'] . "</td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ud/caja[]" id="hiddenField" value="'. $row['ud/caja'] .'">';

    echo "<td>" .  $row['formato'] . "</td>";
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="formato[]" id="hiddenField" value="'. $row['formato'] .'">';

    echo '<td><input type="number" name="cajas[]" id="cajas[]" value=""></td>';
    echo '<td><input type="number" name="sueltas[]" id="sueltas[]" value=""></td>'; 
    echo '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total" value=""></td>';

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="lastValue[]" id="lastValue" value="'. $row['total'] .'">';  
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="proveedor[]" id="lastValue" value="'. $row['proveedor'] .'">'; 


    echo "</tr>";



 }

echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
```

The part I'm not able to figure out is this:

```
if ($row['proveedor']=="Campocerrado" ) 
        { 

        echo "<tr> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th>  <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> </tr>";


         ;
        ;}
```

What I'm trying to do is run the loop until it encounters a specific `$row` to display the html for the row once.

So far, Im getting this :

[image]

But I need something like this to be more precise:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a flag to indicate that you've already output your extra row:

```
$show_extra_row = true;
while(...) {
   if (($row['proveedor']=="Campocerrado" ) && $show_extra_row) {
       $show_extra_row = false;
       echo ...
   }
}
```

After it's displayed for the first time, the flag becomes false and the extra row will never be output again.

Comment: Yep , thats the one! Its very similar answer like Daniels, so you both deserve a points. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sub question, since now I have different problem. I need that extra line whenever that "$row['proveedor']" meets different requirement but  it only displays extra line for the first value whats in the list, not  for every provider.

Comment: then use a state machine: save the proveedor from each line. if that stored value is different than the current value, then you've changed proveedors and output your extra line. basically: `if(proveedor from last line != proveedor from current line) { output extra line }`.

Answer (score 1):

In the pure simplest form of an answer, use a token.

```
$tokenhit = false;
if (!$tokenhit && $row['proveedor']=="Campocerrado" ) { 

   echo "<tr> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th>  
   <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> </tr>";

   $tokenhit = true;


}
```

But i am not sure this answers your true question or not.

Comment: thats not possible if you implemented it properly.  can you update your original question with your new code ?  Did you make sure to put "$tokenhit = false;" before the while loop starts ?

Comment: instead of `!$tokenhit` use `$tokenhit !== true`

Answer (score 0):

you can have a temporary variable to check if the condition already met before.

```
$firstTime = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // trying to a title line 
    if ($firstTime && $row['proveedor']=="Campocerrado" ) 
    { 
        echo "<tr> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th>  <th>TEST</th<th>TEST</th> <th>TEST</th> </tr>";
        $firstTime = false;
    }
    ...
}
```